# .htaccess with query parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I'd like to setup a .htaccess rule to redirect some old URL of this kind

`www.example.com/index.php?id=4&language=deutsch`

to

`www.example.com/deutsch`

with an Apache server using 301 redirections.

How can I catch the language parameter to do this ? Furthermore I'd like to avoid the id param (old URL will be redirected to a single page).

Is this htaccess rule correct ?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*\blanguage=deutsch
RewriteRule ^deutsch [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteUrl` is wrong :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*\blanguage=deutsch
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ deutsch? [R=301,L]
```

The `?` is here to remove the query string in your rewritten url.